# Lua integer won't increment

Tags: lua

I have this simple lua function designed to solve the problem of consecutive prime sum.
The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:

> 41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13

This is the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred.
this is my function:

```
function numOfConsecPrimes(limit)

    a = allPrimes(limit/2)
    length = table.getn(a)
    sumSoFar = 0    innerSum = 0    finalSum = 0
    pos = 1
    items = 0       innerItems = 0  finalItems = 0
    resetpos = pos

    while resetpos < length do
    pos = resetpos
    resetpos = resetpos + 1
    items = 0
    sumSoFar = 0    
        while sumSoFar < limit and pos < length do
            if isPrime(sumSoFar) == true then innerSum = sumSoFar innerItems = items end
            print(sumSoFar)
            sumSofar = sumSoFar + a[pos]
            print(a[pos] .."->"..sumSoFar)
            pos = pos + 1
            items = items + 1
        end
    if innerItems > finalItems then finalItems = innerItems finalSum = innerSum  end
    end
end
```

But for some reason, `sumSoFar` just won't change. I'm printing it before and after the addition of `a[pos]` and it stays zero always. I'm printing `a[pos]` as you see and the values are fine. So what's going on?

Comment: `items = 0       innerItems = 0  finalItems = 0` is same as `items, innerItems, finalItems = 0, 0, 0`

Comment: If you had used local variables, you could have found this with some static analysis.

Comment: In addition to what lhf said, you can also change the metatable for the table of global variables (_G) in order to have it throw an error at runtime when you try to read or write from an undefined global.

Comment: I voted to close as this is just a typo question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is your exact code then you simply have a typo.

```
sumSofar = sumSoFar + a[pos]
```

Capitalize the `f` in the first `sumSofar` so it matches all the other ones.

Comment: Thanks , I knew it was something totally stupid that I missed